# Limitar numero de caracteres en un control textarea que tiene el plugin tinymce

Tags: php, html5, tinymce

tengo en un formulario un textarea, que tiene un editor para que el usuario pueda darle diferentes formatos al texto. Lo hago con tinymce. Ahora bien, necesito controlar la cantidad de caracteres que ingresa, ponele que no quiero que ingrese más de 200 (por decir un numero).

```
<textarea id="detalle" name="detalle" rows="10" maxlength="2000"><?php if (isset($descripcion)) { echo $descripcion; }?></textarea>
```

el textarea lo resuelvo con un maxlenght pero cuando le pongo lo "enlazo" al plugin de tinymce directamente lo ignora... 
que puedo hacer ?

Comment: Ya has buscado en la documentación de tinymce si tienen algo para lograr lo que quieres?

Comment: SI, estuve viendo, gracias... pero creo que cambio de editor, vi el CKEDITOR que tiene una forma muchisimo mas simple para cuantificar no solo caracteres sino palabras / parrafos, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre te queda la forma de hacerlo en javascript :

```
<script>

function limitarTextArea() {
       var texto = document.getElementById('detalle').value;
       if(texto.length < 2000) {
           return(true);
       }else{
           return(false);
       }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: si, eso funciona con el textarea, pero cuando tenes el tinymce no funciona